# Passing user input into $http.get request angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to pass user input into my $http.get request. I am using bootstrap and angular but am confused as I have am trying to pass two dates through a bootstrap modal. I currently have a controller like this

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $http.get("website" + box1 + box2).then(function(r){
    $scope.Data = r.data;
  });
});
```

And a modal in bootstrap with

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">test</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <input id="box1" type="text"/>
  <input id="box2" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  I don't know what to put here to pass it into angular
</div>
```

Comment: `<div class="modal-footer">
 {{Data}}
</div>`

Comment: I'm try to pass the input from box1 and box2 to the controller. Not put the data in the footer

Comment: use `<input ng-model="box1" type="text"/>` (same for box2) along with `$http.get("website" + $scope.box1 + $scope.box2)`

Comment: While that works, it triggers before on page load which is before anyone can input data into it.

Comment: then it needs to be in a function that you can call with something like a button or an event trigger such as `ng-change` on your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http){
 $scope.submit = function(){
  $http.get("website" + $scope.box1 + $scope.box2).then(function(r){
    $scope.Data = r.data;
  });
 };
});
```

In bootstrap modal html make sure this HTML is using testCtrl controller

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">test</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <input ng-model="box1" type="text"/>
  <input ng-model="box2" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button ng-click="submit()" class="btn">Submit(or text you want to keep)</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.box1 = "";
  $scope.box2 = "";
  $http.get("website" + $scope.box1 + $scope.box2).then(function(r){
    $scope.Data = r.data;
  });
});
And a modal in bootstrap with

<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">test</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <input ng-model="box1" id="box1" type="text"/>
  <input ng-model="box2" id="box2" type="text"/>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  I don't know what to put here to pass it into angular
</div>
```

Comment: Would I have to put something in the footer?

Comment: what u need to put in the footer

Comment: This not a solution: (1) there is no need to define `$scope.box1` as empty string, since it's bound to `ng-model`, (2) `$http.get` is called immediately in your controller, which will use those empty strings as a parameter